# Bug in Area 51's questions per day

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51

Recently the "questions" metric on Area 51 for beta sites was replaced by a "questions per day" metric. However, the number does not appear to be calculated correctly - dividing the number of questions on a site with the number of days the site has been in beta does not produce the number listed on Area 51.

This could very well be intentional (closed questions not counting, rolling average, etc) but as it stands it's not very clear where the number is coming from.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's the average number of questions per day over the last two weeks. We should probably put that in the tooltip...

Comment: For accessibility reasons, putting that information in the `title` attribute (in this case on a `div` element) is not sufficient. This makes the information only available to who can use a mouse pointer AND happen to hover over the widget. The information should really be available in plain text.